# I tried to use top keyword but not working

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have not used top so far in PG admin.. Now while going through a YouTube series I came to know about this top keyword..

```
select distinct top 2 salary from salary order by salary desc
```

but it didn't work. Is limit alternate for top and what are the difference that's there in Postgre DB

Can I use this as alternate,

```
select salary from salary order by salary desc limit 2
```

Comment: Do you or don't you want `distinct` ?

Comment: Use `FETCH FIRST 2 ROWS ONLY`, ANSI SQL.

Comment: BTW, PG Admin is for Postgresql. TOP is SQL Server specific. Which one are you using?

Comment: There is no `TOP` keyword available in [`SELECT` syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html).

Comment: FYI "didn't work" is not a good problem description. Did it not return any results? Did it return too many results? Did it give an error (probably, in this case) - and what error exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
select salary 
    from salary    
    group by salary  
    order by salary  desc  
    limit 2
```

Comment: OP is probably using Postgresql.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.. I used select salary from salary order by salary desc limit 2 as alternate and its working fine..

Why am i not able to use top in postgres

Comment: This is because the `limit` does the same thing as the `top`, and you can even use it to set `offset`. Some engines support both.